# Python: Opening auto-generated file

Tags: windows, python-2.7

As part of my larger program, I want to create a logfile with the current time & date as part of the title. I can create it as follows:

```
malwareLog = open(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d - %H.%M " + pcName + " Malware scan log.txt"), "w+")
```

Now, my app is going to call a number of other functions, so I'll need to open the file, write some output to it and close the file, several times. It doesn't seem to work if I simply go:

```
malwareLog.open(malwareLog, "a+")
```

or similar. So how should I open a dynamically created txt file that I don't know the actual filename for...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create `malwareLog` object, it has [`name`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#file.name) attribute which contains the file name.

Here's an example: (my `test` is your `malwareLog`)

```
import random

test = open(str(random.randint(0,999999))+".txt", "w+")
test.write("hello ")
test.close()

test = open(test.name, "a+")
test.write("world!")
test.close()

with open(test.name, "r") as f: print(f.read())
```

You also can store the file name in a variable before or after creating the file.

```
###Before
file_name = "123"
malwareLog = open(file_name, "w")

###After
malwareLog = open(random.randint(0,999999), "w")
file_name = malwareLog.name
```

Comment: Aha, excellent @OSA413! I didn't know about the .name attribute...  Thank-you!